# Symbol distance of double, triple, etc. integrals of CM

Tags: fonts, amsmath, amssymb, integral

Just a curiosity:

> why in Computer Modern (and I think in other some fonts) the double integral signs have *a high distance* of default?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\iint_D f(x,y)\, dxdy\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `amsmath`, the multiple integral signs are spaced using `\intkern@`, whose definition is

```
% amsmath.sty, line 654:
\def\intkern@{\mkern-6mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3mu}{}{}{}}
```

which means that there is a negative kern of 6mu, which is increased to 9mu in display style.

You can modify this default. Here's an example, but of course the redefinition should go in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\iint_D f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$
\end{center}
\[
\iint_D f(x,y)\, dx\,dy
\]
\makeatletter
\def\intkern@{\mkern-9mu\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu}{}{}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{center}
$\iint_D f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$
\end{center}
\[
\iint_D f(x,y)\, dx\,dy
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you immensely, immensely like the title of a song by Umberto Tozzi my favorite singer. Now I ask myself? But isn't the spacing `\def\intkern@{\mkern-9mu\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu}{}` better?

Comment: @Sebastiano It’s a question of personal preferences

Comment: I remember (but may be wrong), that the amsmath package has been updated recently. Many years ago I didn't remember that the two integral symbols had this large distance.

Comment: @Sebastiano Version 2.13, released 2000/07/18, has the same values.